# Iterator for a vector of complex data type

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a structure like below

```
struct voxelParam
{
int voxelID;
int paramID;
}
```

and I have a vector of the structure

```
std::vector<voxelParam*> &finalist;
```

I want to navigate through the vector using iterators

```
for (std::vector<voxelParam*>::iterator it = finalList.end(); it != finalList.begin(); --it)
{
    //I want to get 'it->voxelID' but that is not the way to do it.   
}
```

How do I access the voxelID part using the iterator defined

Comment: Thanks, that works!

Comment: ^Posted as answer for future viewers.

Answer (score 1):

Use `(*it)->voxelID` instead.

Note that `finalist` is a *reference* of a `vector` of `voxelParam` *pointers*. So `*it` gives the value at the `iterator` which is `voxelParam*`, which is then used to access the members via `->`.